# Adding total time in Excel depending on location

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to see if there is a formula I can use to add the total amount of time depending on the location entered into an Excel spreadsheet.

I have attached a screenshot of what I am referring to. If location "B" is entered anywhere in the column, I am wanting to the time spent there to be added to the total time column and have this done automatically if additional entries are made later.

[image: Excel Spreadsheet]
[Second Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTTJr.png)

Please let me know if any clarification is needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you only need to use a couple of sumifs

```
'For B
=sumif("C2:C1000";"B";"B2:B1000")-sumif("C2:C1000";"B";"A2:A1000")
'You can do it for any Location
=sumif("C2:C1000";"A";"B2:B1000")-sumif("C2:C1000";"A";"A2:A1000")
=sumif("C2:C1000";"C";"B2:B1000")-sumif("C2:C1000";"C";"A2:A1000")
```

You only need copy it to your "Resume" Section. So everytime you enter a new entry it will get the total time at location B. You can also extend the range given you are inputing more than a thousand entries.

The explanation of the formula is like this:

```
=sumif(RANGEOFCONDITION; CONDITION; RANGETOSUM)
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! However, I am getting an error when trying to copy it into the spreadsheet. Do they need to be separate?

Comment: @Joe How come? What's need to be separated? Each `=` means that whole line goes in one cell. Maybe due to my locale settings you need to check `;` and `"` if they are proper for your locale formulas

Comment: Okay, I have tried changing it a little bit. It looks like the main issue was using the " with the range. However, I attached a photo. No longer getting an error, but the math is incorrect.  Any ideas? Thanks for all your help

Comment: @Joe Did you check the cell format?

Comment: I was actually just doing that lol. It works perfect! Thank you!